# How to fetch data with pagination using AJAX in LARAVEL PHP

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, pagination

I'm having trouble searching for an answer on how can I fetch data with pagination using an AJAX Laravel. Can someone suggest a tutorial on how can I achieve it. Your answer is very much appreciated. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use Eloquent Paginate method: Laravel using Ajax jQuery. Laravel provides its own library to build the pagination html, which we can easily use in our html page using $model->links() method and $model->paginate() method to make a long list into pagination
   Ref: https://readerstacks.com/laravel-ajax-pagination-example-with-search/
2. Use Ariel Controller / Live wire method

Use make:livewire component and internaly uses $model->paginate()

Ref : https://www.nicesnippets.com/blog/laravel-livewire-search-with-pagination-example